# How to use HTML form validation on button click?

Tags: c#, html, forms, validation, blazor

I'm creating a application using SyncFusion and Blazor. In this application I have a login page which looks like this:

[image]

Using this code:

```
<EditForm Model="@ModelValue">
    <SfTextBox @ref="user" Placeholder="E-mail" Created="@onCreateUser" CssClass="custom-login" Type="InputType.Email" @bind-Value="@ModelValue.Email" required></SfTextBox>


    <SfTextBox @ref="password" Placeholder="Password" Created="@onCreatePassword" CssClass="custom-login" Type="InputType.Password" @bind-Value="@ModelValue.Password" required minlength="7"></SfTextBox>

    <SfCheckBox Label="Stay Signed In" @bind-Checked="rememberUser" CssClass="stay-signed-in-checkbox"></SfCheckBox>
    <SfButton CssClass="forgot-password-button">Forgot Password?</SfButton>

     <SfButton CssClass="login-button" OnClick="validateForm">LOGIN</SfButton>
</EditForm>

@code {
SfTextBox user;
SfTextBox password;
private bool rememberUser;
private User ModelValue = new User();

public void validateForm()
{ 

}

/*ICON*/
public void onCreateUser()
{
    this.user.AddIcon("prepend", "oi oi-person");
}

public void onCreatePassword()
{
    this.password.AddIcon("prepend", "oi oi-key");
}
}
```

In this form are html browser validation popups applied(automatically). These work kind of weird in my situation therefore i created a video illustration it properly:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PhETRPkgDag_DHWYlBFJL1qnodxDpaQ_/view?usp=sharing

As u can see the email field works fine, html form validation occurs every time when button is pressed. In the Password field this is not the case, theres required a minimum of 7 characters and when i press submit button with only 3 characters filled in im not getting any warnings.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the html5 form validation, the `minlength`attribute won't work. If you want to do that validation you should use `pattern` attribute and pass it like `pattern=".{7,}"`. This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10294291/9119186).

If you want to use the blazor validation (which is much better and recommended), you need to use data annotations in your `User` model.

For your particular case, you can use the `MinLength` attribute.

```
public class User 
{
    // other propeties
 
    // Passing data annotations
    [MinLength(7, ErrorMessage = "Password Min Length is 7")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

And for the data annotations validation to work, don't forget that you need to have the `DataAnnotationsValidator` component inside the `EditForm`

```
<EditForm Model="@ModelValue">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    @* rest of components *@
</EditForm>
```